# Random Numbers in a range around a median

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a median and a standard deviation, what i want is to generate random numbers between the median-std and the median+std.

I know how to do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

median=30
std=15
random_nr=rnd.randint(median-std,median+std)
```

I also found the [numpy.random.normal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) function but it doesn't seem to do what i need.
Is there any other way of doing it?
It would be great if the random generator would generate numbers in mirror as to the median, for example, an output for 6 generated random numbers should look like this:

```
numbers=magicfunction(median,std,6)
[29,31,20,40,25,35]
```

Comment: If you can generate them in your code shown, what is your problem then?

Comment: Comparing randint (discrete, uniform, bounded range) with random.normal (continuous, non-uniform, symmetric, unbounded) is a good indication of missing specification or knowledge. Be much more precise! And when some basics are understood, 99% of the use-cases here at SO can be tackled by [Rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) when performance is not the most important characteristic.

Comment: What's the expected distribution? Should each number between the two extremes be equally likely, or do you still want a bell-shaped curve, just with the edges cut off, or only integers?

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel i wondered if there is such a function that would do this for me, like random.normal is.

Comment: @tobias_k i'm trying to randomly fill some values for a Machine Learning train set. I need integers ( in this case they represent years) and they should be between 45 and 15 and their median should be 30, that's why i said i wanted them in mirror, it's probably the easiest way.

Comment: @Mike That still does not answer whether values _near_ the median should be more common that values _far_ from it. Also, given enough samples, the median will automatically be 30; by "mirroring" them you might get some weird effects in the learned model.

Comment: @tobias_k it doesn't really matter if there are more values further away from the median. I'm trying to use this random generator as an alternative to filling the missing data with the Median value. I'd be very much interested to see if there is any real difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, if the size is odd then it will only generate couples (as your request) and then a single number at the end of the array.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

median=30
std=15
def generatearray(median,std,size):
    output=[0]*size    
    for index in range(0,size/2):
        random_nr=rnd.randint(-std,std)
        output[2*index]=median+random_nr
        output[2*index+1]=median-random_nr
    if(size % 2 != 0):
        output[size-1]=rnd.randint(median-std,median+std)
    return output

print generatearray(median,std,6)
```

Comment: Why not just `random_nr = randint(0, std)` and then use `median + random_nr` and `median - random_n`? Would make it much clearer IMHO.

Comment: in that way the first of the couple will always be greater than the median.

Comment: Good point. In this case, use `random_nr = randint(-std, std)`; still clearer than adding `median`, and then subtracting that from `2*median`

Comment: Also, note that the `for` loop is identical for the `if/else`. Instead, just put a `if size % 2 != 0:` after the loop to add the last element.